# Set No match output from an SSIS lookup to a variable

Tags: sql, email, error-handling, ssis

I need to send an email as an error report for data rows that are either no match or fail due to certain business rules. I'm having trouble finding a good way to put all of those failed/no match rows into a variable and then send that variable out in an email.

Comment: Script component ought to do the trick.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18235985/181965 Instead of firing the error event, I'd likely push my `notFound` object into an SSIS scoped Variable (you can only do this in the PostExecute event) and then have a foreach loop shred that object and send out emails as appropriate.

Comment: @Tab I'm going to try the script component. Thanks for the help. I'll reply back when everything is working

Answer (score 0):

**no match**
Source component + Lookup transform to the 'matching table', set the 'Specify how to handle rows' combo box to redirect rows to no match output + row count that sets a variable to the number of rows not matching.

Then further down the line, create a Send Email task that has a precedence constraint, expression, of @that_variable > 0

**fail due to certain business rule**
Pump data into staging table, then an Execute SQL task to execute a stored procedure that does your business rule validation, and returns a value that is however many rows failed.  Again set the result to a variable, and again a Send Email task that has a precedence constraint, expression, of @that_variable > 0

Comment: That'll help them know that N row(s) failed but I think they want the actual details of *these specific rows(s) failed* via their comment of "all of those failed/no match rows into a variable"

Comment: @billinkc you're correct, I need to know all of the details because I'll be sending the email to business users.